Family on vacation get attacked by men in black suits with alien eyes
Family stops at a diner or a gas station before heading up the hills to where they are vacationing. The attendant working at the diner (or gas station) says something weird like, "nobody ever returns". 
The son winds up getting nosebleeds (or ear bleeds) and they find like a diamond implant thing. They have security cameras that see an SUV ram their gate. 
Then guys in black suits start coming with black sunglasses on and then one takes the sunglasses off and he had huge alien looking eyes but it looked human-ish. 
I don't know what happens other than that but in the end, another family is back at the diner (or gas station).
I think the movie came out between 1995-2012.

Closed as a duplicate because it sounds like The Shadow Men. If this isn't the right film, please let me know.
